# Wrong to copy queue to vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, queue

I have a queue that contains data (0 to 14). Assume that 0 has index id 0, 1 has index id 1...and so on

I have two vectors `vector_index_0` and `vector_index_1` that contain index id. Base on these index ID, I want to copy the data from queue to two new vectors, such as `vector_data0` and `vector_data1` (vector_index_0 for vector_data0 and vector_index_1 for vector_data1)

For example, fist element of vector_index_0 is 1, thus I will copy data which has index id 1 to  vector_data0, that is 1, ...

This is my code. I don't know why the output result give wrong answer. Could you fix help me

My expected result must be

```
 First data 
1   2  5    
 Second data 
6   8   9   10
```

But my current result from below code is

```
 First data 
1   2   
 Second data 
5   6   8   9   10
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/2kfry)

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using std::queue;
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec_index_0{1,2,5};
    std::vector<int> vec_index_1{6,8,9,10};
    std::vector<int> vec_index_01{1,2,5,6,8,9,10};//Combine vector index 0 and 1
    queue<int> queue_data;
    std::vector<int> vec_data0;
    std::vector<int> vec_data1;
    int index=0;
    int index0=0;
    int index1=0;
    int j=0;    
    int vec0_size=vec_index_0.size();
    std::cout <<"Queue data"<<"\n";
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
        queue_data.push(i);
        std::cout<< i <<"\t";
    }
    while (!queue_data.empty()) {
        if(vec_index_01[index]==j) {
            if (vec_index_01[index]<vec0_size) {
                vec_data0.push_back(queue_data.front());
                index0++;
            }
            else {
                 vec_data1.push_back(queue_data.front());
                 index1++;
                }
            index++;
            queue_data.pop();
        }
        else {
            queue_data.front();
            queue_data.pop();
        }  

        j++;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n First data \n";
    for(int i=0;i<index0;i++){        
        std::cout << vec_data0[i] <<"\t";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n Second data \n";
    for(int i=0;i<index1;i++){        
        std::cout << vec_data1[i]<<"\t" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have shown us the expected output (or result), but what is the *actual* output? Have you tried using a debugger and step though the code line by line to see where it does wrong?

Comment: As an aside - this is really convoluted code and I am not exactly sure what it is you are trying to accomplish.  I thought I followed it and tried to edit my answer to provide a better solution, but I got lost and am back to being unsure of what you are trying to accomplish.  It certainly feels like a very complicated solution to the problem.

Comment: I just want to copy the data from queue to vector based on the index id. The data corresponds on index id in vector_index_0 will be copy to vector_data_0, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

I think my first answer wasn't what OP wanted.

Maybe the code below is more like it. The code does the following:

```
// if N is present in vec_index_0 -> copy queue element number N to vec_data0
// if N is present in vec_index_1 -> copy queue element number N to vec_data1
// if N is not present in any vec_index -> ignore queue element number N

std::vector<int> vec_index_0{1,2,5};
std::vector<int> vec_index_1{6,8,9,10};

queue<int> queue_data;
std::vector<int> vec_data0;
std::vector<int> vec_data1;
int index=0;

std::cout <<"Queue data"<<"\n";
for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
{
    queue_data.push(i);
    std::cout<< i <<"\t";
}

while (!queue_data.empty())
{
    if ( std::find(vec_index_0.begin(), vec_index_0.end(), index) != vec_index_0.end() )
    {
        // Current queue index found in index vector 0 - copy to data vector 0
        vec_data0.push_back(queue_data.front());
    }
    else if ( std::find(vec_index_1.begin(), vec_index_1.end(), index) != vec_index_1.end() )
    {
        // Current queue index found in index vector 1 - copy to data vector 1
        vec_data1.push_back(queue_data.front());
    }

    // Remove element from queue and increment index
    queue_data.pop();
    index++;
}

std::cout<<"\n First data \n";
for(auto& e : vec_data0)
{
    std::cout << e <<"\t";
}
std::cout<<"\n Second data \n";
for(auto& e : vec_data1)
{
    std::cout << e <<"\t";
}
```

Output:

```
Queue data
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

First data 
1 2 5   
Second data 
6 8 9 10
```

If we put other values in the queue like this:

```
std::cout <<"Queue data"<<"\n";
for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
{
    queue_data.push(2*i + 8);  // Changed here
    std::cout<< (2*i+8) <<"\t";
}
```

it gives:

```
Queue data
8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 
First data 
10 12 18    
Second data 
20 24 26 28
```

Comment: @user8430 - I updated my answer as I think my first answer was wrong

Comment: yeah, I have check it again. It is really true. The above ans was wrong. Can i use your code in the g++ in ubuntu

Comment: It has error is error: ‘find’ is not a member of ‘std’. I am using Kdevelop to build. It need the header #include <algorithm>. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason you are seeing the output you are seeing is this line in your code:

```
if (vec_index_01[index]<vec0_size)
```

`vec0_size` is 3 based on the size of your 0 vector.  Your `vec_index_01` vector contains the 1,2 and then 5.  Everything from there is bigger than 5.  Once `index` is 2 or greater you will never have this if statement return true.  Basically, this if statement is only true while `index` < 2.

Edit - I think this would simplify your code

```
int index0=0;
int index1=0;
int queueIndex = 0;
while(!queue_data.empty()) {
    if (index0 < vec_index_0.size() && vec_index_0[index0] == queueIndex) {
        vec_data0.push_back(queue_data.front());
        ++index0;
    } else if (index1 < vec_index_1.size() && vec_index_1[index1] == queueIndex) {
        vec_data1.push_back(queue_data.front());
        ++index1;
    }
    queue_data.pop();
    ++queueIndex;
}
```

I tested the above code and it produces the output you are looking for.  Here is your whole program cleaned up a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using std::queue;
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec_index_0{1,2,5};
    std::vector<int> vec_index_1{6,8,9,10};
    queue<int> queue_data;
    std::vector<int> vec_data0;
    std::vector<int> vec_data1;

    std::cout <<"Queue data"<<"\n";
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
        queue_data.push(i);
        std::cout<< i <<"\t";
    }

    int index0=0;
    int index1=0;
    int queueIndex = 0;
    while(!queue_data.empty()) {
        if (index0 < vec_index_0.size() && vec_index_0[index0] == queueIndex) {
            vec_data0.push_back(queue_data.front());
            ++index0;
        } else if (index1 < vec_index_1.size() && vec_index_1[index1] == queueIndex) {
            vec_data1.push_back(queue_data.front());
            ++index1;
        }
        queue_data.pop();
        ++queueIndex;
    }

    std::cout<<"\n First data \n";
    for(int i=0;i<index0;i++){        
        std::cout << vec_data0[i] <<"\t";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n Second data \n";
    for(int i=0;i<index1;i++){        
        std::cout << vec_data1[i]<<"\t" ;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If you are going to be using sets of unique indices to split your data you may want to consider actually using the `std::set` instead of a `std::vector` for your index collections.  Then you can just use the find function to see if the index is in the set.  `std::set::find` is logarithmic in its lookup time.  If you are concerned with a logarithmic lookup time you can also consider the `std::unordered_set` which has a constant time lookup.  Here is the code using the `std::set`

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <set>

using std::queue;
int main()
{
    std::set<int> set_index_0{1,2,5};
    std::set<int> set_index_1{6,8,9,10};
    queue<int> queue_data;
    std::vector<int> vec_data0;
    std::vector<int> vec_data1;

    std::cout <<"Queue data"<<"\n";
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
        queue_data.push(i);
        std::cout<< i <<"\t";
    }

    int queueIndex = 0;
    while(!queue_data.empty()) {
        if (set_index_0.find(queueIndex) != set_index_0.end()) {
            vec_data0.push_back(queue_data.front());
        } else if (set_index_1.find(queueIndex) != set_index_1.end()) {
            vec_data1.push_back(queue_data.front());
        }
        queue_data.pop();
        ++queueIndex;
    }

    std::cout<<"\n First data \n";
    for(auto&& it : vec_data0){        
        std::cout << it <<"\t";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n Second data \n";
    for(auto&& it : vec_data1){        
        std::cout << it <<"\t" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank. It must be if (index0 < vec0_size), instead of if (vec_index_01[index]<vec0_size). But If I assume that vec_index_01 only has 1 values such as 1. then index will be increased to 1 after second iteration. Thus if(vec_index_01[index]==j) (line 27) will be crashed (because index=1 but size of vec_index_01 only 0. Why C++ still pass the line)

Comment: @user8430 - I have cleaned up the code a bit and given a cleaner and more readable (in my opinion) loop that chooses the right data values for the indices.

Comment: @user8430 - I have provided a second update showing how to use a std::set which would probably be a better approach if you are going to have sets of unique indices

Comment: Thank for your new approach

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in if condition (vec_index_01[index] < vec0_size), it should be  (index0 < vec0_size).

Comment: @user8430, Thank You.

Comment: Thank. It must be if (index0 < vec0_size), instead of if (vec_index_01[index]<vec0_size). But If I assume that vec_index_01 only has 1 values such as 1. then index will be increased to 1 after second iteration. Thus if(vec_index_01[index]==j) (line 27) will be crashed (because index=1 but size of vec_index_01 only 0. Why C++ still pass the line)

Comment: Sorry it was wrong. I checked it again. Let try with queue data as     for (int i=20;i<30;i++) in line 22

Comment: For this loop you will have only 10 elements, so the array vec_index_1{6,8,9,10} having index 10 is wrong which needs have 11 elements, Try for loop with (int i=20;i<31;i++) having 11 elements.

Comment: Thank. I was wrong it. Sorry I cannot accept two ans. Thank for your ans